# PostgreSQL syntax highlighting in Visual Studio 2017

Tags: postgresql, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

When I create a `.sql` file in Visual Studio 2017 the syntax highlighting assumes I am using MSSQL and highlights valid PostgreSQL queries as having errors.

Is there any way to get Visual Studio 2017 to have proper syntax highlighting in `.sql` files for PostgreSQL?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using a PostgreSQL plug-in, you need to rename your file to either ‘psql’ or ‘pgsql’ to enable to correct syntax highlighting.

Comment: I know this answer is quite old, but I tried to pursue it nonetheless - which "PostgreSQL plug-in" works in this way? I tried "Npgsql PostgreSQL Integration" and it didn't have this effect. https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=RojanskyS.NpgsqlPostgreSQLIntegration